# Merit gem experience level

Tags: ruby-on-rails, merit-gem

I want to know how I can use the points given by merit in rails as experience generated by a user and when the experience reaches a certain level, the user will level up. I just want to know where exactly the points of the user is stored so that I can edit it accordingly as there is not a very clear documentation on merit. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Merit is designed so that badges, ranking and points are orthogonal between each other, so point granting wouldn't be directly coupled to ranking or certain badges.

Nevertheless, you can find the syntax for solving that problem in: https://github.com/tute/merit/issues/64#issuecomment-14958635

Answer (score 0):

Merit uses [Ambry](https://github.com/norman/ambry). This stores to either YAML or a dump file. By default, ambry stores data to `db/ambry.yml`, so take a look here.

Comment: Sorry for not specifying my question properly. I wanted to know which model it uses. I want to do the operations using ActionController